# Does Area 51 have its own history or usage stats?

Tags: discussion, area-51

[image: This is a screenshot of Area 51]

Area51.SE has the usage statistics and other information about all the other Stack Exchange networks except itself. I even searched it on the site and as the screenshot above shows, there is no information available.

Shouldn't it be there? I mean, some would find the page interesting and it makes me feel like Area 51 is left out with pages there for other SE sites.

Comment: There are 10k tools on Area 51 (per the privilege wiki). I don’t know what they contain, though.